# PDO Pagination row by row, stuck at next button and previous button

Tags: php, pdo, pagination

as what my title above, and from the previous page, i've solved my issue about pagination, but now i'm stuck at the next and previous button, i've searhed there are a lot of ways such using javascript and many more, i've tried but i can't display my data instead so here's my code so far :

```
if($typeuser == 'admin'){   
                        $item_per_page = 1;
                        $dbcon = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=laundry','root','');
                        $results = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM konsumen");
                        $results->execute();
                        $get_total_rows = $results->fetch();

                        //breaking total records into pages
                        $pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page);

                        if(isset($_GET["page"])){
                        $page_number = filter_var($_GET["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
                             if(!is_numeric($page_number)){die('Invalid page number!');} //incase of invalid page number
                        }else{
                         $page_number = 1;
                        }
                        $position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);

                        $results = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM konsumen ORDER BY kode_pemesanan ASC LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");
                        $results->execute();
                        while($row = $results->fetch()){
                             print_r ("<table>
                                 <tr>
                                 <td>Kode Pemesanan</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['kode_pemesanan']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Atas Nama</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['atas_nama']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Jumlah Baju</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['jmlhbaju']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Jumlah Celana</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['jmlhcelana']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Jumlah Jaket</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['jmlhjaket']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Jumlah Jas</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['jmlhjas']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Jumlah Dress</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['jmlhdress']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Pengurus Pesanan</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['penguruspesanan']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Status Pesanan</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['statuspesanan']."</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Total Pesanan</td><td>:</td><td>".$row['totalpesanan']."</td>
                                 </tr></table>
                                 <br>
                                 ");    
                        }
```

is there any way for solving the next and previous button ? can i build the next and previous button from php ?

And very big thanks for Jamie, he helps me so much for giving me the clue for php pagination.

Comment: Btw, when doing pagination, you need to use a GET array, not POST. It's unclear as to "how" you're using it here.

Comment: thank you for mention me, i just checked the green check :) , ok i'll change it into GET

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know how that works out.

Comment: so the pagination shows me the rows of the data from my database, and i limit it to show 1 by 1 row, so i've done the pagination but the next problem is i can't get the next row of data, i've tried javascript but my data won't show instead. also the row change everytime i change the value of $page_number

Comment: seeing your edit now from POST to GET; how are you trying to get the prev/next? That isn't in your question/code. Usually, you'd use `file.php?page=x` for an `<a href....>...</a>`.

Comment: yes, i undo my code yesterday and set it as the last it worked

Comment: to which I was right about, as per my comment up there ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, I think you just need buttons that have a dynamic link based on the current request page

```
<?php

// your code as is, dying if page not numeric

if(isset($_GET["page"]) ){
  $next = $page_number + 1;
  echo "<a href='?page=$next'>Next</a>";
} else "echo <a href='?page=2'>Next</a>";
```

Comment: COOL!! really big thanks @jeff  now i see the mistake of me thank you ^^